# Python: Looping over a variable number of inputs

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

Is there a way to efficiently feed in a variable number of inputs into a program like itertools.product() when the number of iterables varies based on user input?

For example, the code below runs, but needs to be explicitly defined for each loop:

```
steps = np.linspace(0,100,21)

if len(elem_list) == 2:
    for phase in itertools.product(steps,steps):
        if round(round(phase[0],10)+round(phase[1],10),10)==100:
            print(phase)

if len(elem_list) == 3:
    for phase in itertools.product(steps,steps,steps):
        if round(round(phase[0],10)+round(phase[1],10)+round(phase[2],10),10)==100:
            print(phase)
            
if len(elem_list) == 4:
    for phase in itertools.product(steps,steps,steps,steps):
        if round(round(phase[0],10)+round(phase[1],10)+round(phase[2],10)+round(phase[3],10),10)==100:
            print(phase)
            
if len(elem_list) == 5:
    for phase in itertools.product(steps,steps,steps,steps,steps):
        if round(round(phase[0],10)+round(phase[1],10)+round(phase[2],10)+round(phase[3],10)+round(phase[4],10),10)==100:
            print(phase)
```

where elem_list contains a variable number of elements input by the user.

Is there any way to write this more concisely and so it can be generally applied to any length of elem_list? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) accepts a `repeat` argument exactly for this. Use it along with `sum` and `map`.

I'm not sure why you need `round` (or `round(..., 10)` for that matter) since `steps` includes whole numbers (so summing them is guaranteed to give a whole number) but this is the way to go.

```
steps = np.linspace(0, 100, 21)

for phase in itertools.product(steps, repeat=len(elem_list)):
    if sum(map(round, phase)) == 100:
        print(phase)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I found that without the round commands I would sometimes get numbers that were very slightly deviated from whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As @DeepSpace mentions, repeat= is the perfect way to handle when all the iterated items are the same.  And that sounds like what you wants.

In more complicated cases, you can use a list of ranges.  And this list can be arbitrarily generated.

```
list_of_ranges = [range(5), (1, 3, 7), range(10), (True, False)]
itertools.product(*list_of_ranges)
```